# How to run "href" without searching element which contains it. C# browser

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I trying to build software which will do some steps on website. I do it by "GetElementById" or "..ByTagName" functions.. But now I step on problem. I have to Invoke member which I can not find by tag, id..

```
<div class="CloseButton">
<a href = "/logout">OK</a>
</div>
```

Now, I want to run just that href. Without searching for "a" tag or anything else. This is only one of many cases which I need to pass.

I tried this did not work for me and that is not what I lookin' for

```
HtmlElementCollection links = webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");

foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
{
    if (link.InnerText.Equals("OK"))
    link.InvokeMember("Click");
}
```

Comment: Why dont you want to search for the <a> tag? \

Comment: More tags which are same... I figure it out.. Just add href behind the current URL..

Comment: webBrowser2.Navigate(  webBrowser2.Url + 
"/indexInternal.es?action=internalStart&acceptDailyLoginBonus=1");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do it without any selector. You could only guess which one is wanted, but you cannot be depended on foreign web.

Comment: Thank you Julius. But it is obvious :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try giving your href an ID:

```
<a href="/logout" id="logout">OK</a>
```

and:

```
var link = webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("logout");
link.InvokeMember("click");
```

Comment: The web is not mine so I could not :D